# Finding matches from an object of class "call" in R

Tags: r, function, subset, eval

Given the ***function call*** object `a`, I was wondering how I could find instances of `n` for which `control` is `T` and `F`, also how to know what is the value of `long` for each of such cases?

For example, in the below case, I expect to ***subset*** `31 32 35` as `n`s for which control is `T` and `30 33 34` as `n`s for which control is `F`.

The same goes with `long`. In other words, I'm looking for a subsetting strategy from a `call` object?

```
foo <- function(n , long, control, ...){

 match.call()
}

# Example:
a <- foo(n = 30:35, long = c(1, 2, 2, 3, 1,1), control = c(F, T, T, F, F, T))
```

Comment: Can you show the expected output.  It is not clear.  instances of n for which control is T and F.  Not clear

Comment: please, try to explain a little bit more about the problem.

Comment: Why you need to do this in this way.  It is much easier to do `n[control]` inside the function

Comment: does this `lst1 <-  as.list(match.call());
  eval(lst1$n)[eval(lst1$control)]` work

Comment: you can do do `as.list(a)` and then do the same

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If we need to get the value from 'a'

```
lst1 <- as.list(a)
eval(lst1$n)[eval(lst1$control)]
#[1] 31 32 35
eval(lst1$n)[eval(lst1$control) & eval(lst1$long)==1]
#[1] 35
```

Comment: @rnorouzian  what is the condition for 'long' to ssubset

Comment: @rnorouzian  sorry, I am not getting you

Comment: @rnorouzian  Did you meant `eval(lst1$long)[eval(lst1$control)]#
[1] 2 2 1`

Comment: @rnorouzian `a` is a `language` object, which I split into a list of language object and was `eval`uated.

Comment: You can use `f2 <- function(obj1, nm1, nm2) { lst1 <- as.list(obj1); eval(lst1[[nm1]])[eval(lst1[[nm2]])]}`